# In Eclipse, how can I create relocatable project definitions?

Tags: eclipse

For my project, due to the long build and regression times, it is extremely common for me to have up to 4 different sandboxes at different NFS locations.  Moreover, people can't share eclipse project definitions between each other.  I'd like to be able to check in project definitions into the repository so that when I check out a new sandbox, eclipse knows that all project definitions are relative to the top directory of the sandbox.  Can I do this?

( Note: as a first approximation, I'm not too concerned about merge issues.  I just want to get rid of the overhead of recreating a project definition each time I check out a different sandbox.  I'll worry about merging project/configuration files some other day..  I realize that if you had multiple people somehow sharing a project configuration, things like breakpoints and run commands could proliferate uncontrollably.)

Comment: But which part of a .project file is **not** relocatable? I've never had a problem sharing .project files across a team with wildly different workspace locations.

Comment: I previously saw issues with hard-codings in .pydevproject

Comment: If you were more specific about "issues", you might get better answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Eclipse project set files can help you here:

http://wiki.eclipse.org/PSF